# Promised payment for leaving previous job without notice hasn't been paid - how to get it?

Tags: job-change, notice-period

I joined my new employer about a month ago and when joining the new company offered to pay me an additional sum to cover what I lost for leaving my last job without notice. This money was due to be paid along with my first month's salary however I haven't received it. As the agreement to pay this money was only verbal between us what would be the best approach to getting this money paid?

Comment: I've edited your question to try and make it on-topic for this site so we can help. Hopefully I haven't strayed too far from what you intended to ask, if I have feel free to revert my edit and try one of your own.

Comment: In additions to Neo's answer, get all mentions of promised payment sent to you **in writing** in the future.

Answer (score 3):

> As the agreement to pay this money was only verbal between us what
>   would be the best approach to getting this money paid?

First, ask your **manager**.  If your manager is unable to help, then *talk with your companies HR* department.

If those two courses of action are unsuccessful, you may want to look at legal action, although this will be **tough** as you do not have *anything in writing to back up your claim*.